# TypeScript type definition for Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am looking for a Typescript type definition for the latest Bootstrap (3.x). On DefinitelyTyped the latest is for Bootstrap 2.2 .  Or what is the recommended workaround if there is no Typescript type definition available for a library (version) we want to use and we don't have the time to write it ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/bootstrap

There you can find all other definitions

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

(Star repo if you work with TS - it's very useful )

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for not getting it, the one i find there is 2.2, where can i find the other ones?

Comment: I check at http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/ - suppose - no. Maybe some one start create definitions, but didn't share them. You can do it ) It helps many others

Comment: sure i heard about the benefit of sharing yet this is for a Saturday afternoon quick hack so no time to do things thoroughly